# First Countable Spaces are Hausdorff or Not?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Does first countable imply Hausdorff? If not, what is an example of first countable space that is not Hausdorff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org) is a database of topological spaces inspired by Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*. It lists the following twenty-two first countable spaces that are not Hausdorff. You can learn more about any of them from the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=First%20Countable%2B%7E%24T_2%24).

Compact Complement Topology

Countable Excluded Point Topology

Countable Particular Point Topology

Deleted Integer Topology

Divisor Topology

Double Pointed Reals

Either-Or Topology

Finite Complement Topology on a Countable Space

Finite Excluded Point Topology

Finite Particular Point Topology

Hjalmar Ekdal Topology

Indiscrete Topology

Interlocking Interval Topology

Nested Interval Topology

Odd-Even Topology

Overlapping Interval Topology

Prime Ideal Topology

Right Order Topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Sierpinski Space

Telophase Topology

Uncountable Excluded Point Topology

Uncountable Particular Point Topology

Comment: I haven't checked the others, but the Sierpinski space is certainly first countable.

Comment: +1 but your link 'search result' link seems to be broken? This https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=%20~t_2%20%2B%20First%20Countable works (as of writing this comment). I'm not editing your answer because you seem to be involved in that project, so you might want to know of changes. Best wishes.

Comment: I'm one of the current maintainers of the project and have submitted an edit request updating the search query.

Answer (score 12):

Consider any topological space with at least two points and the indiscrete topology: It is first countable but not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 7):

As mathmax points out, first countability doesn’t imply even the weakest separation axiom, $T_0$. Moreover, adding some separation doesn’t help: first countability doesn’t imply Hausdorffness even for $T_1$ spaces, since the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $\Bbb N$ is first countable and $T_1$ but does not have any disjoint non-empty open sets.

Comment: Perhaps "even the weakest [of the better known] separation axiom[s]", for those who know about $R_0$ topological spaces. FYI, this question was recently bumped to the front page, if you're wondering why I'm replying to a 2+ year old answer. (I didn't realize this answer was 2+ years old until I finished and was reading over my comment before clicking "Add Comment".)